# Break into Goldbach's safe

Tags: knowledge, cipher, computer-puzzle, number-theory, password

You need to unlock a safe by typing in the correct password. All you have is the following note:

> 5101216429918933541175819375754311977470728893977974053502952628004830200066913358490313939657011283996554248679751960067799456833385973491180810546439419511054758188819591642086783446840805291939266542651397802763957203603872522037468171369937150488334327367887021211651743386426815128607541508758043216285865873671575671600533540790034686766260273498787830380052705630254574619771306940252220669399877490534732311208332493719176748171146266754890481517914627070988337499999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999996611
>
> Sincerely,
>
> C. Goldbach

What is the password?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding

> $3389$ to the number given (to get to the next multiple of a large power of ten) yields 
>  $2^{80}\cdot 3^{65}\cdot 5^{83}\cdot 7^{83}\cdot 11^{87}\cdot 13^{79}\cdot 17^{82}\cdot 19^{68}$

Translating the exponents from decimal to ASCII gives:

> PASSWORD